# Запретить браузеру переводить определенные блоки с текстом

Tags: html, html5

Предусмотрена ли возможно, запретить перевод браузером, определенные блоки с текстом на страницe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте атрибут `translate`, со значением `no`: `translate="no"`.